# c++ Algorithm to convert an integer into an array of bool

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code an algorithm that will save to file as binary strings every integer in a range. Eg, for the range 0 to 7:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Note that the leading zeros and spaces between digits are essential.

What I cant figure out how to do in a simple way is to convert the integers to binary numbers represented by `bool []`s (or some alternate approach).

**EDIT**

As requested, my solution so far is:

```
const int NUM_INPUTS = 6;
bool digits[NUM_INPUTS] = {0};
int NUM_PATTERNS = pow(2, NUM_INPUTS);

for(int q = 0; q < NUM_PATTERNS; q++)
{
    for(int w = NUM_INPUTS -1 ; w > -1 ; w--)
    {

        if( ! ((q+1) % ( (int) pow(2, w)))  )
            digits[w] = !digits[w];

        outf << digits[w] << " ";
    }

    outf << "\n";
}
```

Unfortunately, this is a bit screwy as the first pattern it gives me is 000001 instead of 000000.

This is not homework. I'm just coding a simple algorithm to give me an input file for training a neural network.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it as such

Comment: I think you want to do some base conversion instead. Google **C++ base 2**

Comment: Binary data is not the same as an array of bools... are you supposed to create your own binary representation of numbers too?

Comment: @Lirik the array of bools is what I'm after.

Comment: @Shahbaz this isn't homework. I just need a program to automatically generate an input file for a neural network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `pow`. Just use binary math:

```
const int NUM_INPUTS = 6;
int NUM_PATTERNS = 1 << NUM_INPUTS;

for(int q = 0; q < NUM_PATTERNS; q++)
{
    for(int w = NUM_INPUTS -1 ; w > -1; w--)
    {
        outf << ((q>>w) & 1) << " ";
    }
    outf << "\n";
}
```

Comment: How does `1 << 6` = 64? I'm not familiar with the `<<` or `>>` operators.

Comment: `x << n` shifts the value `x` to the left by `n` bits. If you prefer, it doubles the value `x`, `n` times. 1, in binary, is "0000_0001". 1 Shifted left 6 times is "0100_0000". In base 10, that is 64. Similarly `x >> n` shifts the value `x` to the *right* by `n` bits (or halves `x`, `n` times). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Answer (score 3):

Note: I'm not providing code, but merely a hint because the question sounds like homework

This is quite easy. See this example:

```
number = 23
binary representation = 10111
first  digit = (number   )&1 = 1
second digit = (number>>1)&1 = 1
third  digit = (number>>2)&1 = 1
fourth digit = (number>>3)&1 = 1
fifth  digit = (number>>4)&1 = 1
```

Alternatively written:

```
temp = number
for i from 0 to digits_count
    digit i = temp&1
    temp >>= 1
```

Note that the order of digits taken by this algorithm is the reverse of what you want to print.

Comment: int compare = 1L << (digits_count - 1); digit i = (temp & compare ? 1 : 0); temp <<= 1;

Comment: In case you're wondering, that'll let you take the digits in the order you wanted...

Comment: @OrgnlDave, I wasn't wondering, it was obvious. I only intend to give the OP a hint though, and let him tackle with the problem himself.

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way would be to use std::bitset.

Example:

```
#include <bitset> 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 8; ++i){
    std::bitset<3> b(i);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If you want to output the bits individually, space-separated, replace `std::cout << b << std::endl;` with a call to something like `Write(b)`, with `Write` defined as:

```
template<std::size_t S>
void Write(const std::bitset<S>& B)
{
  for (int i = S - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    std::cout << std::noboolalpha << B[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @MattMunson: Now that I have access to a real computer with a real screen and a real keyboard, I added an example.